# Implementing an Abstract Class

Tags: c++

I am a C++ noob and I have a noob question.

I have an abstract tree class definition in a header file. I know it is abstract because it contains virtual methods. It looks like so:

```
//AbsTree.h

class AbsTree { 
   public:
       AbsTree();
       virtual ~AbsTree() =0;
       virtual void accept(Visitor &visitor) const = 0;
       virtual void execute(Env &ctxt) const throw (InappropriateFunction);
};

class Operation: public AbsTree{
   public:
      Operation(char oper);
      virtual ~Operation();
      virtual void accept (Visitor &visitor) const;
      char getOperator() const;
   private:
      char operator;
};
```

I have come up with the following implementation of this AbsTree:

```
AbsTree.cpp

#include "AbsTree.h"

AbsTree::AbsTree() {}
AbsTree::~AbsTree() {}
AbsTree::accept(Visitor &visitor) const{}
AbsTree::execute(Env &ctxt) const {}

Operation::Operation(char oper): operator(oper) {}
Operation::~Operation(){}
Operation::accept(Visitor &visitor) const{}
char Operation::getOperator() {
   return operator;
}
```

So I try to compile the .cpp via:

```
g++ AbsTree.cpp -o AbsTree
```

and I get

```
AbsTree.cpp:3:1: error: 'AbsTree' does not name a type
AbsTree.cpp:4:1: error: 'AbsTree' does not name a type
AbsTree.cpp:5:1: error: 'AbsTree' does not name a type
AbsTree.cpp:6:1: error: 'AbsTree' does not name a type
AbsTree.cpp:8:1: error: 'Operation' does not name a type
AbsTree.cpp:9:1: error: 'Operation' does not name a type
AbsTree.cpp:10:1: error: 'Operation' does not name a type
AbsTree.cpp:11:6: error: 'Operation' has not been declared
AbsTree.cpp: In function 'char getOperator()':
AbsTree.cpp:12:9: error: 'operator' was not declared in this scope
```

Please expose me for the C++ noob that I am.

Comment: @Namfuak: AbsTree.cpp does not  contain a main method, what you see is everything.

Comment: Are you sure this is all the code where you see the symbol `AbsTree`?

Comment: Maybe there's some error preventing `AbsTree` from being defined. (e.g., maybe you forgot to include a header declaring `Visitor`?)

Comment: is `accept` pure virtual function? then you can't implement it. and `execute` need return `void`

Comment: @BryanChen [It is possible to implement pure virtual functions.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9757b32adff7fed3)

Comment: you are missing `void`. i.e. **void** AbsTree::accept(Visitor &visitor) const{}

Comment: `operator` is a reserved keyword. Don't use it as a variable name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a compilable/runnable version of your code (runnable at [ideone here](https://ideone.com/Ef22JU))

```
struct Visitor { };
struct Env { };
struct InappropriateFunction { };

class AbsTree { 
   public:
       AbsTree();
       virtual ~AbsTree() =0;
       virtual void accept(Visitor &visitor) const = 0;
       virtual void execute(Env &ctxt) const throw (InappropriateFunction);
};

class Operation: public AbsTree{
   public:
      Operation(char oper);
      virtual ~Operation();
      virtual void accept (Visitor &visitor) const;
      char getOperator() const;
   private:
      char operator_;
};

AbsTree::AbsTree() {}
AbsTree::~AbsTree() {}
void AbsTree::accept(Visitor &visitor) const{}
void AbsTree::execute(Env &ctxt) const throw (InappropriateFunction) {}

Operation::Operation(char oper): operator_(oper) {}
Operation::~Operation(){}
void Operation::accept(Visitor &visitor) const{}
char Operation::getOperator() const {
   return operator_;
}

int main()
{
    Operation o('x');
    Visitor my_visitor;
    o.accept(my_visitor);
    o.getOperator();
}
```

Basically, you've got to take more care to make sure the functions you define match your declarations - that includes `const` and `throw` specifications and return type.  Further, `operator` is a reserved keyword and you can not use it to name your own variables.

Separately, exception specifications are deprecated... best to leave them out as they never proved useful.  (C++11 has a `noexcept` keyword that's occasionally useful if you want to make it clear that a function can be used in code making exception guarantees - might get a little extra optimisation too, but if an exception is raised in/under the function your program will call `std::terminate`).

Answer (score 2):

AbsTree is an abstract class, like you said. This means that you need to create a **derived** class in order to provider an implementation.

```
// ConcreteTree.h

#include "AbsTree.h"

class ConcreteTree : public AbsTree {
   public:
       ConcreteTree();
       virtual ~ConcreteTree();
       virtual void accept(Visitor &visitor) const;
       virtual void execute(Env &ctxt) const throw (InappropriateFunction);
}
```

Then:

```
// ConcreteTree.cpp

#include "ConcreteTree.h"

ConcreteTree::ConcreteTree() {}
ConcreteTree::~ConcreteTree() {}
ConcreteTree::accept(Visitor &visitor) const{}
ConcreteTree::execute(Env &ctxt) const {}
```

Comment: So the definition of AbsTree in the .h file does not need any implementing in the .cpp file, only the derived classes?

Comment: Well, the `= 0` methods are called "pure virtual" methods. You cannot provide an implementation for them. But for the others, yes, you need some sort of default implementation.

Comment: @metacubed, you can in fact provide implementations for pure virtual methods. You can also call pure virtual methods by qualifying them with the base class name.

Comment: @Brian well yes.. but isn't that really a corner case? The `= 0` forces you to override it in a derived class anyway. I understand where it might be useful, but let's keep that for more advanced use cases :)

Comment: I have added another class definition that derives AbsTree, and I have edited the .cpp file to implement the Operation class. I am still however receiving errors.